# Can "pouvoir" be translated/interpreted to meanings other than "can" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions

(I was not exactly certain on how to phrase this question, so bear with me.)

The majority of times when French learners encounter the verb *pouvoir*, they think of the word as its common English counterpart *can*; However, I was curious to know whether it should be thought as *to have the ability; be able to perform an action*

For example in this case:

> Mon frère était ravi de pouvoir me parler encore !

To represent

> My brother was ecstatic to be able to talk to me again !

Another example:

> Il voulait pouvoir y participer ce soir, puisque sa femme l'avait empêché d'y participer hier.

For

> He wanted to be able to participate in it tonight, since his wife had prevented him from participating yesterday.

There may be some instances, such as this:

> I want to have the ability to make my own decisions.

Where you could use *pouvoir* in this instance ?

> J'ai envie de pouvoir prendre mes propres décisions.

**Can pouvoir presented as such, if so would it be more practical to think of it as such when translating/interpreting ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary meaning of 'pouvoir' is "to have the power to", but it is widely used in many different context (ability, possibility, permission) so that a translation out of context is quite difficult.

In your first example, it seems that the ability is stressed, but maybe he was expecting that I would not talk to him anymore because of some very disappointing behaviour.

In your second example, the permission is stressed. (his wife did not want him to go).

Your last sentence makes sense to me, but you need to remove the **de**

> J'ai envie de pouvoir prendre mes propres décisions.

EDIT: Comme j'essaie de l'expliquer dans mon pauvre anglais, le verbe pouvoir s'utilise dans beaucoup de situations: c'est une valeur sûre! Cependant, cette diversité peut nuire à la bonne compréhension de la phrase hors contexte, donc il vaut parfois mieux utiliser un terme plus précis.

Si vous me dites "j'ai envie de pouvoir prendre mes propres décisions", la première interprétation qui me vient à l'esprit est qu'une autorité (parent, patron...) prend toutes les décisions à votre place (et vous devez toujours obéir).

Avec  "j'ai envie d'avoir l'occasion de prendre mes propres décisions", vous vous êtes émancipé de cette autorité mais les circonstance ne vous ont pas encore offert la possibilité (les événements se sont enchaînés trop vite pour qu'une décision puisse se prendre). Le verbe **pouvoir** s'utilise aussi dans ce sens-ci, et la construction est moins lourde, donc votre choix doit se baser sur le contexte (en privilégient la simplicité à l'orale et la clarté dans un texte officiel).

Comment: Actually, I would not say "have the permission", but "have the **power**", which is the literal translation. I think that applies to all cases, because if you don't have permission and you cannot do it without permission, then you are powerless! "Je n'ai pas le droit mais je peux quand même !"

Comment: I agree. I would even say "have the **opportunity** / **possibility**"

Comment: thank for the constructive comment, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Diriez-vous que c'est mieux d'employer *avoir l'occasion de* vs *pouvoir* ?

Comment: Merci de l'avoir rédigé en français, c'est facile de comprendre ! :) Votre anglais n'est pas du tout pauvre ! Mon français est trop mauvais pourtant. Pour clarifier ceci, généralement ça représente la permission de faire quelque chose plutôt que l'occasion.